# Speech to text in phonegap/android

Tags: android, cordova, speech-recognition, phonegap-plugins, speech-to-text

I am developing an android/phonegap application. I have a form which is to be filled by the customer. My client wants me to design form which would take voice input and convert it into text. Now, I have following set of questions/clarification,

1. Every android phone running above 2.1 has voice search capability, so there is no need to add that functionality as part of the app?
2. If i am implementing that functionality as part of my app, where should i implement that - in android or in phonegap ? . I guess in phonegap since my UI is in phonegap. I have test Speech Recognize phonegap plugin and its working like a charm!! [URL :http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/12/2/Adding-voicebased-search-to-a-PhoneGap-app](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/12/2/Adding-voicebased-search-to-a-PhoneGap-app)
3. If i am implementing that functionality as part of my app, do i need any supporting google app (specifically: GoogleServicesFramework and voice search) to be installed?

Hope I have made my point clear, Please do relpy as its urgently required..

Thanks,

Nanashi

Answer (score 1):

I went with first approach... Thanks for looking into it,

Nanashi